# Ruby: How to make program return nil if there is nothing in location of table

Tags: ruby, csv

In Ruby I have this csv file:

```
make,model,color,doors,email
dodge,charger,black,4,practice1@whatever.com
ford,focus,blue,5,practice2@whatever.com
nissan,350z,black,2,practice3@whatever.com
mazda,miata,white,2,practice4@whatever.com
honda,civid,brown,4,practice5@whatever.com
corvette,stingray,red,2,practice6@whatever.com
ford,fiesta,blue,5,practice7@whatever.com
bmw,m4,black,2,practice8@whatever.com
audi,a5,blue,2,practice9@whatever.com
subaru,brz,black,2,practice10@whatever.com
lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com
```

and this is my code:

```
def delete_from_data
    print "\nTo delete a car, enter the email (this is case sensitive): \n> "
    delete_car = gets.chomp

    #this allows me to delete a certain row based on email
    table = CSV.table("cars.csv")
    table.delete_if do |row|
        row[:email] == delete_car
    end
    File.open("cars.csv", "w") do |f|
        f.write(table.to_csv)
    end

    #this shows the updated student roster after deleting user
    puts "\nThis is the updated roster after deleting: #{delete_car}"
end
```

Having this code, how can I make it if the user enters an invalid email (misspelled email or anything that doesn't match an email from the CSV file), it asks to enter a valid one since the one they typed isn't an email from the CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `table` *first*.

Now you can use `#any?` to see if any rows contain that email address.

```
table.any? { |row| row[:email] == delete_car }
```

Now, just do this in a loop, breaking the loop and returning the input email when the input email address is in the table.

```
delete_car = loop do
  email = gets.chomp
  break email if table.any? { |row| row[:email] == email }
  puts "Invalid input. Try again."
end
```

You may also wish to generate a set of valid email addresses. If you think you'll need to loop several times, this may lead to better performance.

```
valid_emails = table.map { |row| row[:email] }.to_set

delete_car = loop do
  email = gets.chomp
  break email if valid_emails.include?(email)
  puts "Invalid input. Try again."
end
```

Comment: I tried running the first block of code that starts with "delete_car = loop do" and when I enter a valid email address from the CSV file, it doesn't break the loop and it keeps saying invalid input no matter what is inputted

Comment: _Exactly_ what input did you try?

Comment: I inputted "practice11@whatever.com" since it was one of the emails in the CSV file but it does not break the code after

Comment: Change `row["email"]` to `row[:email]`. Using a string rather than a symbol may be the issue.

Comment: so that fixes that issue but it doesn't update the csv file

Comment: That's a different issue than the question asked. _Having this code, how can I make it if the user enters an invalid email (misspelled email or anything that doesn't match an email from the CSV file), it asks to enter a valid one since the one they typed isn't an email from the CSV file_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248847/discussion-between-burner-and-chris).